# How to set default value of a TextBox if TextMode=Number in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASPN.NET TextBox with TextMode set to Number, like this:
`<asp:TextBox ID="SampleTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Number" Step="0.01" Min="0"></asp:TextBox>`

In Page_Load I tried to set the default value this way:
`SampleTextBox.Text = "123.456;`
but when the page appears the textbox is empty. Can somebody explain this? Thanks.

I tried everything but the default value was never shown. The answer for the same question with TextMode=Date helped a lot.